# asp.net core razor class library pages not always accessible after building

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1 final project using a razor page dll in VS 2017 15.7.3 When testing the razor pages in the dll are not always found when testing in the browser. Usually a complete rebuild and test will allow the page to be found.

The layout is as follows:

Razor DLL:

```
Pages/Home/myHome.cshtml
```

Web app:

```
Pages/Index.cshtml
```

The URL / will always work. The URL `/Home/myHome` only works one a complete clean\rebuild. A simple build and test, and myHome pages won't be found.

Also, publishing to an azure web app won't find the page either.

So, it appears something is working and not working based on how something is built. Any ideas or is an RC type bug?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a bad Azure Web App setup. Once the asp.net core 2.1 bits went final, and Azure was updated. I had to delete the webapp, and create a new one. Then after publishing to the new web app, all worked as expected.